# ReferenceError: function is not defined when calling from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to create a bookmarklet functionality similar to the thefancy.com site, I created a bookmarklet button which when clicked loads a js file which is located on some other website http://wonderstreet.localhost.com and append it in the head section of the current document, it then creates a iframe and append it in the body of the current document.

The above mentioned js file contains various functions which I need to call from this iframe, for example, there is a "Close" button in the iframe which when clicked should call the function which is located in the above js file (this function will close or remove the iframe)

The iframe gets created and displayed correctly.(I need to fetch all the images of current document and show it in iframe)
Problem is that when I click close button it says: ReferenceError: function is not defined
Can somebody please help and let me know how can I solve this ?
**[I am using core javascript and not jquery]**

Here is the code from the js file =>

```
function create_bookmarklet_iframe(thewonderstreet_userid) {
 var ifra=document.createElement('iframe');ifra.src="http://localhost.com/index.php/image_picker?userid="+userid;ifra.setAttribute("id","bookmarklet_iframe");ifra.setAttribute('allowtransparency',true);ifra.setAttribute('style','width:279px;height:372px;border:1px solid #4c515c;position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:10000001;margin:0;background-color:#eff1f7;');void(document.body.appendChild(ifra));
```

}

```
function remove_bookmarklet_iframe(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

And this is the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:%20(function%20()%20{%20%20%20%20%20userid%20=%20'724c5a0e49e4dac588a90e17233982493027197d';%20%20%20%20%20var%20search_url%20=%20'http://localhost.com/javascript/bookmarklet_js.js';%20scripts_finder%20=%20document.getElementsByTagName('script');%20var%20found_url%20=%200;%20for%20(var%20i%20=%20scripts_finder.length;%20i--;)%20{%20var%20actual_url%20=%20scripts_finder[i].src.split("?");%20if%20(search_url%20==%20actual_url[0])%20{%20found_url++;%20}%20}%20if(found_url%20<=%200)%20{%20s=document.createElement('SCRIPT');s.type='text/javascript';s.src='http://localhost.com/javascript/bookmarklet_js.js?_='+(Math.random());document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);%20}%20%20var%20s_id%20=%20'bookmarklet_iframe',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s_avail%20=%20document.getElementById(s_id),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20can_continue%20=%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t;%20%20%20%20%20if%20(s_avail)%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20can_continue%20=%20false;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Alreadyopen');%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function()%20{%20if%20(can_continue)%20{%20create_bookmarklet_iframe(userid);%20}%20},1000);%20})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself, what I was doing was wrong, instead of creating an iframe I used div, so basically I eliminated iframe, created div by javascript and appended it to document body.